# i am not getting the exact output for my C program

Tags: c, arrays, string

The problem is : Write a C program to covert lowercase letters to uppercase letters and vice versa of string S.
1<=S<=100

EXAMPLE:

INPUT

```
HelloWORLD
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
hELLOworld
```

INPUT

```
RanDoM
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
rANdOm
```

My code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{ char s[100];
int i;
for (int j=0; j<=100 ; j++)
{
 scanf("%s",&s[j]) ;
}
for (i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z')
        {
            s[i] = s[i] - 32;

        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = s[i] +32;

        }

    }
    for (int k=0; k<=100 ; k++)
    {    
        if (s[k]!='\0')
      {  printf("%c",s[k]) ; }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

The OUTPUT which I am getting is:

INPUT

```
HelloWORLD
```

Current OUTPUT

```
hELLOworldԯ@ _�"����ԯ8_�"�>sn�"�
```

INPUT

```
 RanDoM
```

Current OUTPUT

```
rANdOm�
�$@0�������$H����>sη��
```

What changes in the code do I need to make so that I can get rid of the symbols at the end of the word?

After all the suggestions and help I have found the code which gives the expected output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {  char str[100];
 scanf("%s",str);
       int i;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(str); i++)
        {    
            if (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'&& str[i]!='\0')
            {
                str[i] = str[i] - 32;

            }
            else if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z'&& str[i]!='\0')
            {
                str[i] = str[i] +32;

            }

        } 
         printf("%s",str);
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you wasting time with scanf?  Read one character at a time.  Convert it.  Print it.  Move one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023921/2970947

Comment: `int main(void) { int c; while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF ) { putchar( isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : toupper(c) ); }}`

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Also, str[100] is out of bounds.  Fix your input loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hi There some extra code in your program and some mistakes also. I am doing some correction in your program to complete your task.

- I am not writing new code for your better understanding
- I am not removing lines, just commenting those lines and giving reason in line comments
- You should read all comments and remove before use.
- For any confusion ask in comment section

```html
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    
    int main()
    { char s[100];
    int i,j,k;
    
     //Loop not required
     //for (j=0; j<=100 ; j++)
     //{
      scanf("%s",&s[j]) ;
     //}
    for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
     //You should have to compare with ASCII or use string methods like islower
    
     //if (s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z')
     if (s[i]>= 97 && s[i]<= 122) // ASCII for a-97 and z-122
     {
         s[i] = s[i] - 32;
     }
     else //u may put a check here for upper case to handle errors
     {
         s[i] = s[i] + 32;
    
     }
    
        }
    
        //No loop or if statement required
       // for (k=0; k<=100 ; k++)
        //{
          // if (s[k]!='\0')
         // {
         printf("%s",s) ;
           // }
        //}
    
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: Use `<ctype.h>` then `isalpha`. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and help.

Comment: Welcome @YashMeshram